# System could not find the environment option that was entered (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10

system could not find the environment option that was entered

the "System could not find environment option/variable entered" is still coming up when I try to run .exes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does this relate to your previous question? Did you manage to restore your environment variables yet?

Comment: This is the same question, can you fix it?

Comment: If this is the same question, it's a duplicate and should be removed.

Comment: yes is my question i deleted all environvemt ect

Comment: We know it is your question and this one has been flagged as a duplicate, that's all. Please don't post duplicates.

Comment: thanks you to all i solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing environment variable might be `windir` whose value is
`C:\Windows`.

Other important variables are:

```
COMSPEC=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
HOMEDRIVE=C:
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
```

If you have difficulty adding these variables in normal boot, try
booting in Safe mode.